# Angular Form exact 10 alphanumeric letters pattern validation

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I have the following problem with this specific use case of a reactive form field validation.

At the moment I only set this rule:

```
this.projectForm = this.fb.group({
  .....................................................................................,
  .....................................................................................,
  .....................................................................................,
  CIG: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10),Validators.maxLength(10)]],
```

at the moment I am checking if the value inserted into my **CIG** form field have exactly 10 charachers as lenght.

My problem is that I have to check also that this is an alphanumeric string (composed of exactly 10 characters).

So something like this is allowed: **ABCED12345** but somethint like this is not allowed: **ABCD-12345**

How can I implement this behavior using **Validators**? I need to use REGEX or something like this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use Angular Reactive Form [Pattern Validators](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern) to achieve this.

```
validPattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]{10}$"; // alphanumeric exact 10 letters
this.projectForm = this.fb.group({
 ...
 CIG: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.validPattern)],
```

Hope this address your issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can also create your own custom validator function if you want more control over your error messages, and add it to your validators array.
Such a function can be something like:

```
import { FormControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';

const ALPHA_NUMERIC_REGEX = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$/;
const ALPHA_NUMERIC_VALIDATION_ERROR = { alphaNumericError: 'only alpha numeric values are allowed' }

function alphaNumericValidator(control: FormControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    return ALPHA_NUMERIC_REGEX.test(control.value) ? null : ALPHA_NUMERIC_VALIDATION_ERROR;
}
```

And add it to your validator list like so:
like so:

```
[Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10),Validators.maxLength(10), alphaNumericValidator]
```

For more information on angular custom validators:
[custom validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators)